# Reduce PDF document size through C#

Tags: c#, pdf, compression

I am having my PDF documents having image in it with the size of almost 12MB.
Now I also need to email that document as an attachment.Which is not allowing to simple Compressing and Decompressing techniques mentioned in earlier forums.
Please suggest me any alternative for this through C# code.

Comment: you may split pdf and later merged in to single pdf file

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227984/fast-pdf-compression-library-for-net?rq=1) thread

Comment: Hello Shyam sundar,
In my case the PDF file is having size of 12MB and I need to send that 12MB file as attachment thru email to my customer.So I cannot use compression-decompression type of logic here.But I need any tool/utility/code which reduces the size from 12MB to say for e.g. 2-3MB.And also at the same time the quality of image in PDF file should not be compromised.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try reducing PDF file size with Ghostscript.

You can read more about reducing PDF file size solution with Ghostscript here: [Reducing PDF file size using Ghostscript on Linux didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850776/reducing-pdf-file-size-using-ghostscript-on-linux-didnt-work)

If you want to use Ghostscript with C#, you can call it from a command line or by using Ghostscript wrapper for .NET: **https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com**